# The function $f(x,y)=\dfrac{x}{y}$

Tags: optimization

My concern is: Why the hessian of the function $f(x,y)=\dfrac{x}{y}$ is semidefinite positive by deducing from the quadratic form method, although, its determinant is negative ??

$$\nabla^2f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \dfrac{1}{y^2} \\
\dfrac{1}{y^2}  & \dfrac{-2x}{y^3}  
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$(x,y)\nabla^2f(x,y)\begin{pmatrix}
x  \\
y   
\end{pmatrix}=0$$

Comment: Aren't some minus signs missing?

Comment: Just three missing!  That's all that can be missing here $\cdots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual Hessian is the negative of what you show.

The determinant of the Hessian is negative. Therefore, the Hessian has one negative eigenvalue and one positive eigenvalue. The Hessian is indefinite. The Hessian is NOT positive semidefinite.

Therefore, $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}$ is neither convex nor concave.

**Edit**: Your mistake is using the same (x,y) in the quadratic form that you use in the calculation of the Hessian. That is not correct. The correct way is to choose an (x,y), calculate the Hessian $H$ at that (x,y), and then consider any $(x^*,y^*)$ at which to evaluate the quadratic form $(x^*;y^*)^TH(x^*;y^*)$. You will see that for some choices of $(x^*;y^*)$, the quadratic form is negative, for others it is positive, and for others, it is zero.

Comment: Yes you are right, but why the quadratic form method gives the value zero

Comment: Please show exactly what you did on the "quadratic form method", and how that gives what you say is a contradctory result.

Comment: We know that f is convex if and only if $\nabla^2f(x)$ is positive and semidefinite. which implies $x^T \nabla^2 f(x) x \geqslant 0$. If we apply this on our function we will find $x^T \nabla^2 f(x) x=0$

Comment: Your mistake is using the same (x,y) in the quadratic form that you use in the calculation of the Hessian. That is not correct. The correct way is to choose an (x,y), calculate the Hessian $H$ at that (x,y), and then consider any $(x^*,y^*)$ at which to evaluate the quadratic form $(x^*;y^*)^TH(x^*;y^*)$. You will see that for some choices of $(x^*;y^*)$, the quadratic form is negative, for others it is positive, and for others, it is zero.

Comment: Thank you so much !!

Comment: @My question You can accept the answer if you are now satisfied.

Comment: Yes you were right and thank you